# Generation of one million random numbers but of length four

Tags: mysql, random

is there any way by which we can generate a 1 million random numbers of length four between 0-9999? Then i have to store them in a MySql DB, Language which i am using is Java.

Comment: What do you mean by "of length four"?

Comment: By length four means that each generated random number will have maximum length of four. For Example 9999.

Comment: Yes...but what is the _minimum_ length/value of each generated number?  You are not being clear here.

Comment: minimum legth could be 1 and maximum length must not exceed 4.

Comment: So some numbers will be repeated several times?

Comment: Also, you are confusing number generation and number display. 0 and 0000 are the same thing . The difference is only one of formatting

Answer (score 1):

MySQL (excluding MariaDB) does not seem to support any built in sequence generating capability.  Given that you are using Java, I might actually handle your problem there.

If you want a MySQL solution, then here is one option.  We can generate an on-the-fly sequence of length 1 million, using a numbers table/CTE with cross joins.  If you are using < MySQL 8, then just replace the CTE with an inlined table.

```
WITH digits AS (
    SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9        
)

INSERT INTO rand_table (val)
SELECT RAND()*10000
FROM digits d1
CROSS JOIN digits d2
CROSS JOIN digits d3
CROSS JOIN digits d4
CROSS JOIN digits d5
CROSS JOIN digits d6;
```

Comment: Will all generated numbers ranging between 0-9999 have length of four or not?

Comment: Yes, they will, because I am selecting `RAND()*10000`, which will always return a number between 0 and 9999.  And I am inserting 1 million values.

Comment: Purpose of asking this question was that i want to fix length of field 4 in which rand numbers will be stored. After your answer it is cleared.

Comment: basically i was in confusion that is it possible to generate 1 million rand numbers but each rand number have length less then 4.

Comment: Yes 0000 to 9999

Comment: Then try my answer.  Its logic seems to be what you want.